# Correlation between categorical variables with Groupby

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, correlation, predict

I have the following table, **cat_data**:

```
 organization_id  amount       date       mcc    category   category_id 
0   4026          221.13    2017-03-07  3504.0  Lodging 268       1
1   4029          671.40    2017-03-08  3000.0  Airfare 269       1
2   4045          116.10    2017-03-10  3000.0  Airfare 269       1
4   28              0.00    2017-05-25  5734.0  Uncategorized   1054
5   28              89.00   2017-05-25  5734.0  Uncategorized   1054
```

**What I am trying is** to determine if mcc is a predictor for category_id. I want to group by organization_id and see if within that organization, mcc is a predictor for category_id. 
Ideally I'd be able to look across organizations and see if mcc is a predictor for category_id as a whole, but have the model only check mcc/category_id codes within the organization_id group (each group has different category_ids, so if I don't group, the regression doesn't work). Category_id and mcc are multi-class. When I run this code:

```py
cat_data.groupby('organization_id')['mcc', 'category_id'].corr()
```

I get:

```
organization_id         
                   mcc          category_id
1   mcc          1.000000        0.085130
category_id      0.085130        1.000000
2   mcc          1.000000        -0.302497
category_id      -0.302497       1.000000
```

When I ran this:

```py
    cat_data.groupby('organization_id')['mcc', 'category_id'].corr().unstack().iloc[:,1].mean()
```

I got **0.0138** as the average. Would that be how I interpret the influence of mcc on predicting category id?

I could use some guidance on where I am going wrong. The goal is to see whether mcc and category_id are correlated and whether mcc can be used as a predictor to predict category_id.

Comment: Hi @supremedata, welcome to Stack Overflow.  I assume `category_id` is some form of ordinal encoded categorical variable?  If so, correlation in this context makes no sense and shouldn't be applied.  See [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119835/correlation-between-a-nominal-iv-and-a-continuous-dv-variable) for further information.  Unless your question here can be rephrased as a programming one, it should either be deleted or moved to another site.  See what questions you can ask on this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your response. Yes category_id is an int and mcc code is a float. Both are not continuous but categorical. Do you have any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: I would look into either multiple Chi Squared tests with the Holm correction to manage Type I errors, or a multinomial logistic regression.  `sklearn` can handle multiclass logistic regression out of the box but doesn't give nice summary data (as you get with R).  You could look at [statsmodels multinomial logistic regression model](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.MNLogit.html) too.

Comment: @Chris this is so helpful thanks! I just have 1 question: I also want to group by organization_id & see if within that organization, mcc is a predictor for category_id. Ideally I'd be able to look across orgs & see if mcc is a predictor for category_id as a whole but have the model only check mcc/category_id codes within the organization_id group (each group has different category_ids so if I don't group the regression doesn't work). Do you have any suggestions for how to train, test, split while grouping & aggregate the results to see in total whether mcc is a predictor for category_id?